# Delete record from cosmos db based on size

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a requirement where if records in my collection exceeds 50 Mb then i need to delete those records from cosmos db. how will i achieve this?

Please help on this.

Comment: As currently described, this sounds like an unusual requirement. Are you trying to limit record size to 50MB or actually aiming to delete the full record once it exceeds 50MB? Or are you perhaps trying to find existing records that exceed this size?

Comment: actually aiming to delete the full record once collection size exceeds 50MB

Answer (score 0):

The recommended practice would be to set up an [`Alert rule and do an action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/monitor-accounts#set-up-alerts-in-the-portal) based on the condition.

[image]

You can also call a webhook to do the necessary action.

Answer (score 0):

Another cost effective way to do it through Cosmos DB trigger. Write an trigger for Cosmos DB. Trigger body should check size and delete the document.

Comment: Sorry,I am new to trigger and main logic to check documents size in collection.How will i get that? Can you please elaborate on this